# What is the way to share files with somebody using only cloud storage and a phone number?

Tags: file-sharing, cloud-storage

Let's say two persons would like to share files with each other without knowing each other's emails, using messengers or social networks, but they do know each other's phone numbers.

First thing that comes to mind is to upload it to One Drive or Google Drive and send the link via SMS-message, so that the other person would type it in the address bar. But links are complicated and long.

Files have to be downloaded using PC's Internet, not phone's.

Comment: How long must the link be accessible?

Comment: Don't most text (sms) apps recognize URL's and make them clickable? Otherwise, just use any other messaging app such as Whatsapp to send a link to the shared file.

Comment: This question comes down to, use a method of communication that accepts phone numbers (whatsapp, telegram, etc) and send a link through any service that provides one, such as wetransfer, google drive, etc... because the options are quite big here, this question is highly opinion based.

Comment: @Berend, LPChip - _"But links are complicated and long."_ I think the essence of this question is how to get the random, not user-friendly link from the computer to a phone.

Comment: @gornostaj from an hour to a day.

Comment: @Berend it's preferrable to use computers Internet to download big files, not phones, that's going to cost a lot.

Comment: @LPChip it has to be downloaded via PC, not phone.

Comment: @gronostaj I agree completely, but that wasn't clear from the original question

Comment: There are many ways to get an arbitrary text from a phone to a pc. For instance, the Windows 'My Phone' app, synchronized browser tabs, using Whatsapp in the (pc) browser, etc.

Comment: Whatsapp, Telegram and other communication services all have a PC variant so you can get the link directly on your computer. Also usually on your phone you have email installed. You can email the link to yourself so you can get the link on your computer and open it then. Really this is not going to be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [YellKey](https://www.yellkey.com/) to generate a short-lived human-friendly alias to the sharing link. YellKeys use real English words, so they are harder to get wrong than randomly generated IDs. YellKeys live up to 24 hours.

Alternatively, you can use some method to send the SMS using your computer. Google [has a service for this](https://messages.google.com/) for Android users. It lets you read and write messages on your phone using a computer. There are also 3rd party alternatives such as Pushbullet. This method isn't time-limited, but both sides have to use it: first to send the link, then to open it on a computer.